# JMS Publish Scriber to Same topic but sender should not receive his own generated message

Tags: jms

I am new to world of JMS and stuck in an issue. Here it is; 
Suppose I have one topic and all the clients are publishing and subscribing to same topic. What i want to achieve is this if ClientA publishes a message to the topic then all the other clients should receive that message but ClientA (Sender should not receive his own message returned back).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the subscriber to ignore messages published from the current connection.
This is done by setting the **noLocal** option when creating a subscriber.

See [How can I prevent receiving JMS messages that I have produced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636240/how-can-i-prevent-receiving-jms-messages-that-i-have-produced/6637083#6637083).